# I get "Access Token not found in cache" error while using Paypal Order API

Tags: next.js, paypal, access-token, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented Login with Paypal feature in my app and now I have stored the access_tokenf from the user. Now when I call the create order API, and then later capture order API, I get this error.

```
{
  error: 'invalid_token',
  error_description: 'Access Token not found in cache'
}
```

I have even tried to verify and see if token is not expired, and it isn't but still I get this error.
I even tried to add the access_token in cache using `memory-cache` but still same error.

I am doing these API calls from /api nextJS backend side.
So i first call my backend like /api/create-order and then in there
I am doing the call, like this

```
import dbConnect from "@/helpers/dbConnect";
import PaypalUser from "@/models/PaypalUser";
import axios from "axios";
import cache from "memory-cache";

const checkAccess = async (gmail) => {
    axios
        .post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_URL+"api/paypal/access", {
            gmail: gmail,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.data.success) {
                if (!res.data.check) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    axios
                        .post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_URL+"api/paypal/refresh", {
                            gmail: gmail,
                        })
                        .then((res) => {
                            if (res.data.success) {
                                return;
                            } else {
                                return;
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        const { gmail } = req.body;
        await checkAccess(gmail);
        const user = await PaypalUser.findOne({ gmail: gmail });
        if (user) {
            const { access_token, expires_in } = user;
            cache.put("access_token", access_token, expires_in);
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
            myHeaders.append("Prefer", "return=representation");
            myHeaders.append(
                "Authorization",
                "Bearer " + access_token
            );

            var raw = JSON.stringify({
                intent: "CAPTURE",
                purchase_units: [
                    {
                        items: [
                            {
                                name: "Plan 1",
                                description: "This is a plan 1",
                                quantity: "1",
                                unit_amount: {
                                    currency_code: "USD",
                                    value: "100.00",
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: "100.00",
                            breakdown: {
                                item_total: {
                                    currency_code: "USD",
                                    value: "100.00",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            });

            var requestOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: raw,
                redirect: "follow",
            };

            fetch(
                "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders",
                requestOptions
            )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result)
                    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Order created", order_id: result.id });
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "User not found" });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Method not allowed" });
    }
};

export default dbConnect(handler);
```

`/api/paypal/access` code

```
import dbConnect from "@/helpers/dbConnect";
import PaypalUser from "@/models/PaypalUser";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const { gmail } = req.body;
        const user = await PaypalUser.findOne({ gmail: gmail });
        if (user) {
            const { last_time, expires_in, refresh_token } = user;
            const now = new Date().getTime();
            if (last_time + expires_in < now) {
                // token is expired
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, check: true, message: 'Token is expired' });
            } else {
                // token is not expired
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, check: false, message: 'Token is not expired' });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'User not found' });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Method not allowed' });
    }
}

export default dbConnect(handler);
```

`/api/paypal/refresh` code to update `access_token` using `refresh_token`

```
import dbConnect from "@/helpers/dbConnect";
import PaypalUser from "@/models/PaypalUser";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        const { gmail } = req.body;
        const user = await PaypalUser.findOne({ gmail: gmail });
        if (user) {
            const { refresh_token } = user;
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append(
                "Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            );
            myHeaders.append(
                "Authorization",
                "Bearer {my base64 encoded clientID and secret}"
            );

            var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
            urlencoded.append("grant_type", "refresh_token");
            urlencoded.append("refresh_token", refresh_token);

            var requestOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: urlencoded,
                redirect: "follow",
            };

            fetch(
                "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
                requestOptions
            )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then(async (result) => {
                    const { access_token, refresh_token, expires_in } = result;
                    // console.log(typeof access_token,typeof  refresh_token,typeof  expires_in);
                    const now = new Date();
                    const last_time = now.getTime();
                    const user = await PaypalUser.findOne({ gmail: gmail });
                    if (user) {
                        const user2 = await PaypalUser.findOneAndUpdate(
                            { gmail: gmail },
                            {
                                access_token: access_token,
                                last_time: last_time,
                                expires_in: expires_in,
                            }
                        );
                        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: user2 });
                    } else {
                        const user3 = await PaypalUser.create({
                            access_token: access_token,
                            refresh_token: refresh_token,
                            last_time: last_time,
                            expires_in: expires_in,
                            gmail: email,
                        });
                        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: user3 });
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("error", error);
                    res.status(400).json({ success: false });
                });
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "User not found" });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Method not allowed" });
    }
};

export default dbConnect(handler);
```

Comment: `api/paypal/refresh` what is this endpoint? Where did you get it from? What are the .NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_URL and gmail parameters being thrown around?

Comment: Getting an access token is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/ , your question should focus on showing where you are implementing this and a log of the request and response.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I have updated the post, please see now and `NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_URL` is just the http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using identity Log in with PayPal / Identity API tokens as if they were client_credentials for API calls. They are not. They are only for obtaining information about a user's account.

For API calls, there are two options:

- First party API calls: use the client ID and secret provided by the account that is going to receive the payments. They must log in to  https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/live to obtain credentials for a REST app.
- Third party API calls:

(a) Use your own API actor client ID and secret and specify a `payee` in the v2/checkout/orders API request body

or

(b) For certain APIs such as v2/payments Refunds and Captures, specify a PayPal-Auth-Assertion HTTP header with a JWT token that encodes the payer_id of the account being operated on.

All of this is documented on the PayPal developer references depending on which API operation you are trying to do; since your code shows v2/checkout/orders look at using your own client_id and secret to get an access token (NOT using the Identity API nor authentication_code nor a refresh_token, those have nothing to do do with grant_type=client_credentials) along with `payee` to specify the account that will be receiving the payment.

Comment: I want the users to connect their account and just click pay button on checkout page, and then they are not asked for their credentials again, I use the already made connection and make the payment. For this purpose, what should I do then?

Comment: In that case, none of your code nor the above will apply. For the US, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/ . For other major countries, wait some months or contact PayPal for options. Most previously existing options for billing agreements with reference transactions etc are old and have been deprecated.

Comment: So, when it means for US only, then by that they mean that business account should be US only or customers account also should be US only?

Comment: The business account